# C#: Counting iEnumerable object

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the count of the elements stored in a Ienumerable object. There is no count property for this so how do i get the count for the var object?

Thanks

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168901/howto-count-the-items-from-a-ienumerablet-without-iterating

Comment: The `IEnumerable` doesn't necessarily know how many elements it has. The only thing it knows for sure is that it can be enumerated. When (or even if) it ever hits the end is a detail beyond the scope of `IEnumerable`.

Comment: maybe ienumerable isnt the best way to do this... Initially i am trying to use LINQ to XML to read a bunch of elements in an xml. For ex school.Elements("Student"); this returns an ienumerable elements type object. Is there a way to just get it as an arraylist for examle?

Comment: use `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()` to get it as a countable object. The reason it returns an `IEnumerable` is because it doesn't execute your selects/filters until you try to do something with it (like `foreach` over it). The `IEnumerable` is just a placeholder; also called a "lazy" implementation.

Comment: hmm just tried the .ToList() but it gives an error. Only .ToString() is available? DO i need an addtional cast somewhere?

Answer (score 14):

You could use the [Count()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) extension method starting from .NET 3.5:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> foos = ...
int numberOfFoos = foos.Count();
```

Make sure you've brought it into scope by:

```
using System.Linq;
```

And don't worry about performance, the `Count()` extension method is intelligent enough not to loop through the enumerable if the actual type is for example a static array or a list in which case it would directly use the underlying `Length` or `Count` property.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do anything with an `IEnumerable` other than iterate over it.

So, to get the count, you would have to write this code:

```
int count = 0;
foreach(var item in enumerable) {
    ++count;
}

// Now count has the correct value
```

To save you the awkwardness, LINQ provides the [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038.aspx) extension method which does just that. You will need to do `using System.Linq` to use it.

Also, be aware that, depending on the nature of the `IEnumerable`, it might not be possible to iterate over it more than once (although this is admittedly a rare case). If you have such an object in your hands, counting the number of items will effectively render it useless for future work.

Comment: Actually it's not always required to iterate.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168901/howto-count-the-items-from-a-ienumerablet-without-iterating/853478#853478  The `Count` extention method actually check to see if it's an `ICollection` and if it is just returns the `Count` property from `ICollection`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `Count()` method. Enumerables have no `Count` property.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to call ToList first if you finally want to convert it  to a list.
Especially when your lambada expression binds an outer variable:

```
string str = "A,B,C";
int i = 0;
var result= str.Split(',').Select(x=>x+(i++).ToString());


var count = result.Count();
var list =result.ToList();

//Now list content is A3 B4 C5, obviously not you want.
```