# Check if IEnumerable has ANY rows without enumerating over the entire list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lazy-loading, ienumerable

I have the following method which returns an `IEnumerable` of type `T`.  The implementation of the method is not important, apart from the `yield return` to **lazy load** the `IEnumerable`.  This is necessary as the result could have millions of items.

```
public IEnumerable<T> Parse()
{
    foreach(...)
    {
        yield return parsedObject;
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

I have the following property which can be used to determine if the `IEnumerable` will have any items:

```
public bool HasItems
{
    get
    {
        return Parse().Take(1).SingleOrDefault() != null;
    }
}
```

Is there perhaps a better way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Howto: Count the items from a IEnumerable<T> without iterating?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168901/howto-count-the-items-from-a-ienumerablet-without-iterating)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`IEnumerable.Any()` will return `true` if there are any elements in the sequence and `false` if there are no elements in the sequence. This method will not iterate the entire sequence (only maximum one element) since it will return true if it makes it past the first element and false if it does not.

Comment: Oh, I never knew about this overload of `Any`. But would it not also have to iterate at least once?

Comment: No, it does not iterate. The Any method will return true if it makes it past the first item.

Comment: This is not correct. It does begin to iterate the enumerable, however it does not iterate the entire thing.

Comment: But it does not iterate the full sequence, only one item.

Comment: @davenewza this is a linq method. Implemented as so: http://pastebin.com/Acq7WL0E

Comment: @Marcus That's what I asked in my comment.  But great, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Uatec:  I am aware of `IEnumerable.Any(Func)`, I just didn't know about this parameterless overload.  Thanks

Comment: @BraveNewMath Works for me in LinqPad **if(!Addresses.Any()) {
 Addresses.Dump();**
}

Comment: @forcewill I trued it just now, and I didn't get the error. must have been a some other issue with the way the query was written. I don't have it anymore.

Comment: Be aware this can cause some unexpected effects. For example, if you first check for enumerable.Any() and then enter the foreach to enumerate your enumerable, you'll loose the first element of that enumerable, due to the way Any() works - it has already called e.MoveNext() once.

Comment: No, that is incorrect. Any will do a MoveNext but the collection will not be modified and a following foreach will start at the first item (index = 0). This is easy for you to test yourself!

Comment: The following foreach will start at the first item, but it will be a new enumeration. This means that you might get unexpected side effects: https://pastebin.com/y2AJvyKY

Comment: @MladenB. you're confusing `IEnumerable` with `Enumerator`. The former produces the latter. `Any()` will use `GetEnumerator()` and indeed consume from that `Enumerator`, however any subsequent LINQ use will use a _new_ `Enumerator`. -- *However* depending on the source `IEnumerable` that may or may not produce the original item. For arrays and lists this will not happen, but with streaming enumerables you could indeed loose items.

Comment: @Marcus what I tried to say is not that Any() modifies the sequence, but rather that your enumerable will be enumerated twice (if it's for example an SQL query). Any() calls MoveNext() which means it starts enumerating your sequence, so if you have a foreach loop right after a call to Any() (seen this so many times), your SQL query will be executed twice. That's the important thing I tried to draw attention to. If you materialize your enumerable into an in-memory collection, you won't feel this effect, of course, because your data is already stored in memory and accessed from there.

Comment: @Bouke exactly like you said. It's just my poor choice of words... See my previous comment.

Comment: @MladenB Yes, then I understand you, but I have no reason to believe that we are not talking about direct access to memory at this point and I would say, in most cases today, working with a database is normally using some sort of ORM and using IQueryable, but yeah, I agree.

Answer (score 9):

Similar to [Howto: Count the items from a IEnumerable<T> without iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168901/howto-count-the-items-from-a-ienumerablet-without-iterating) an `Enumerable` is meant to be a **lazy**, read-forward "list", and like quantum mechanics the act of investigating it alters its state.

See confirmation: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GPMVXH

```
    var sideeffect = 0;
    var enumerable = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => {
        // show how many times it happens
        sideeffect++;
        return i;
    });

    // will 'enumerate' one item!
    if(enumerable.Any()) Console.WriteLine("There are items in the list; sideeffect={0}", sideeffect);
```

`enumerable.Any()` is the cleanest way to check if there are any items in the list.  You could try casting to something not lazy, like `if(null != (list = enumerable as ICollection<T>) && list.Any()) return true`.

Or, your scenario may permit using an `Enumerator` and making a preliminary check before enumerating:

```
var e = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
// check first
if(!e.MoveNext()) return;
// do some stuff, then enumerate the list
do {
    actOn(e.Current);  // do stuff with the current item
} while(e.MoveNext()); // stop when we don't have anything else
```

Comment: And updating the fiddle with the enumerator shows that the preliminary check, while still evaluating the enumerable 1 time (i.e. `sideeffect++`) doesn't result in _extra_ enumeration: https://dotnetfiddle.net/no3WoH

Comment: be aware that using Any(Func<int, boo> predicate) will generate "side effects"
https://sharplab.io/#gist:60dd304540eee9eec3effb59ec1bb94d

Comment: @NathanSmiechowski yes that's what my example/fiddle is meant to show -- `sideeffect` is incremented once every time you call `.Any(with or w/o a predicate)`, since it has to enumerate at least one item from the list.

Answer (score 6):

The best way to answer this question, and to clear all doubts, is to see what the 'Any' function does.

```
   public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
            if (e.MoveNext()) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs