# How would I convert my foreach code to normal for loop?

Tags: c#

```
IEnumerable<MyRequest> myRequestsList = myRequests;

foreach (MyRequest request in myRequests)
{
    myResults.Add(ProcessMyRequest(userId, request));
}
```

please convert it to for loop in a better way

Comment: Well, what is the original type of `myRequests`? *Why* are you trying to convert the loop into a for loop? Do you know how the compiler expands `foreach` loops?

Comment: No i don't know please explain me.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398982

Comment: There are a number of possible ways to change code using `foreach` into code using simply a `for` loop. None seem obviously _better_ than using `foreach`, and the ones that seem obvious to me all also seem worse. If you want an answer, you should explain your question better; what form of `for` loop are you looking for, and what is your broader goal in changing the code in this way?

Comment: See also: [foreach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx)

Comment: I wan to make it fast.

Comment: @rafi - why do you think `for` is faster than `foreach`?

Comment: My code just reviewed by my boss. He said to change like that. He said it will be a performance issue

Comment: `List<MyRequest> myForList = myRequests.ToList(); for(int index = 0; index < myForList.Count; index++) { myResults.Add(ProcessMyRequest(userId, myForList[index])); }` will be oh so much faster you wouldn't believe it... (sorry for the sarcasm, but with bosses like that, you probably can't argue that this kind of premature optimization is just plain wrong)

Comment: For and foreach differ slightly in performance. They are approximately the same speed. But the foreach loop uses more stack space for local variables.

Comment: @NeillVerreynne - yes, full agreement on that. On the other hand, if the difference between `for` and `foreach` is the bottleneck, then we're in a whole other realm of performance (time *or* space) needs.

Comment: Speaking of optimization: use `MyRequest[] myForList = myRequests.ToArray();` instead. -- Also, hope that `myRequests` is finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some bad news: if you insist on using `IEnumerable` [you don't have a direct Count() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168901/howto-count-the-items-from-a-ienumerablet-without-iterating). You can use the code like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < myRequests.ToList<string>().Count; i++)
{
    // use the index!
}
```

But I think this is way more costly than the foreach().
The same answer suggests using `ICollection` over `IEnumerable`