# How can I count the number of elements in IEnumerator?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ienumerator

I am getting all files in a directory by following code.

```
IEnumerator FILES = Directory.GetFiles(
                DIRECTORY_PATH).GetEnumerator();
```

How can I get the total number of files? There's no `FILES.Count();`

Comment: `int count = Directory.GetFiles(DIRECTORY_PATH).Length;`?

Comment: `Directory.GetFiles(..)` returns a `string[]` - i.e. an array. This has a `.Length` property on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count the items from a IEnumerable<T> without iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168901/count-the-items-from-a-ienumerablet-without-iterating)

Comment: Is there any reason that you need Enumerator from GetFiles(string) method? As already been suggested, GetFiles(string).Length will do just fine.

Comment: In general, if all you have really is an `IEnumerator` instance, the way to get the count is to enumerate while counting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\yourdir").Length
```

will give you count directly

Comment: Fixed. To much used to Linq that I forgot about return type

Comment: @GiladGreen it's true that there's no 'need' for 'System.Linq' here. Anyway, since an array is an `ICollection`, a LInQ `Count()` [is optimized to](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/R/41ef9e39e54d0d0b.html) directly access the `Count` property of the `ICollection`; which in turn [returns the `Length` property of the array](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/array.cs.html#680).

Answer (score 1):

First you can get your files `string[]`, count the numbers in it, then get your enumerator:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(DIRECTORY_PATH);
int count = files.Length;
IEnumerator enumerator = files.GetEnumerator();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to stick with "`GetEnumerator()`" ...

```
IEnumerator files = Directory.GetFiles(DIRECTORY_PATH).GetEnumerator();
int count = 0;
while (files.MoveNext())
{
    count++;
}

// after this loop you will have total files count in count varibale.
```