# Conditionally take some, or all, items

Tags: c#, linq

How can I add a condition to my `Take()` call?

```
query.Take(isTrue ? 10 : 0);
```

Instead of 0, I would like to take all the items returned by the query.

Comment: You provide no context to this question, My first instinct tells me whatever condition youre trying to check in isTrue should be checked before the Take(), you could get Count() items of your list, but that would be really inefficient and wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you *really* want to use the conditional operator then this would be the way to proceed:

```
var result = query.Take(isTrue ? 10 : query.Count());
```

Although, I have to admit if `query` is an `IEnumerable<T>` then this is suboptimal compared to the other answer.

if by any chance it's a list then an equivalent version in terms of performance would be:

```
var result = query.Take(isTrue ? 10 : query.Count);
```

Comment: Putting a link to how bad "suboptimal" can be would be useful :-) But they are difficult to find (the good ones)... This link is suboptimal too :-) https://stackoverflow.com/q/28756/613130

Comment: @xanatos depends on the use case I guess but "sub-optimal" sometimes doesn't matter at all ;-). I'd say if you like code golfing like me then I'd proceed with the current approach unless I know it will cause me performance issues but then again others would argue if it's production code then I'd use the `if` statement for readability et al...

Comment: Just to be super clear. "Suboptimal" means that it enumerates the **entire** list to get the count (so best case its now enumerated twice)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET as mentioned that depends what type `query` _actually_ is. depending on the actual type, one can avoid "enumerating twice".

Comment: Sure; I thought that was clear but this only applies to the `IEnumerable` case :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Right, but still saying "so best case its now enumerated twice" is false. best case is actually _once_.

Comment: Ok, best case *if you are doing this with an `IEnumerable`* is enumerating twice. Better?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET close but not quite, even _if you are doing this with an IEnumerable_ it will only enumerate _twice_ if `isTrue` is false. now that's much better ;)

Comment: Ok, fair enough :)

Answer (score 5):

There isn't really an "All" parameter to `Take` but you can conditionally apply the clause.

```
IEnumerable query = something;
if (isTrue)
   query = query.Take(10);

...
```

Comment: Why to take all the items and create overhead on system when we only required 10 items.

Comment: @habib You aren't unless you put a `ToList` in the wrong spot (lazy enumeration). This is just explicitly writing the same line that `.` chaining does